# Insertar variable js en php

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código, y lo que necesito es introducir el valor de la variable `customerId` en el key del array en `php`

*La variable php **$customer** contiene un array*

```js
var customerId = $(this).val(); // valor numérico
$(".customerinfo").append("<p><?php echo $customers[" + customerId + "]["NAME"]; ?></p>");
```

Comment: No es posible, PHP se ejecuta en el servidor, enviando el contenido de la página al navegador, que es donde se ejecuta Javascript y no hay forma de que interactúen, a menos que lo hagas por medio de [AJAX](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494)

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente lo que deseas no es posible ya que ambos lenguajes se ejecutan en lugares diferentes, mientras que `JS` es por lado del cliente, todo lo que tenga que ver con `PHP`será ejecutado del lado del servidor, lo más conveniente para tu problemática sería hacer la conexión mediante **AJAX** para que puedas pasar datos desde tu `JS` hasta tu archivo `PHP`.

Si no tienes conocimiento aún sobre estos temas, o apenas estás viéndolos, quizá compartiendo más a fondo tu problema o lo que deseas hacer, junto con trozos de código nos facilitaría el poder ayudarte a hacer lo que planteas.